# Prevent flextable from repeating headers when breaking through pages

Tags: r, flextable

I have seen that on the GitHub version there's now the feature to allow page breaks when adding flextables through (`body_add_flextable()`). However, the header is repeated through all the pages where the table is placed.

Is there a way to prevent this? Or maybe this is a future feature that could be implemented and I'm getting ahead of myself, as I've seen the breaking the table through pages is pretty recent.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want the headers repeated?  Understanding the need may let us consider other approaches.

Comment: Just standard report style in my company.

Comment: It seems like it is not an option? https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/160